# WP_Query result in form of Rest API results

Tags: wp-query, json

This is simple posts result array.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
$posts = $query->posts; // returns simple array of data
```

Is there a way to get the results from wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed without making extra request to server to pull json and then decode to php array?

Looking for something like that:

```
$posts = $query->rest_posts(); // for example ??
```

Comment: you can retrieve a list of posts and its properties with this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: get_posts() is the same as WP_Query()->posts. What I'm looking for is Rest API json result without using curl or file_get_content() as it makes extra request to server.

Comment: `WP_Query` (and so `get_posts()`) don't use a HTTP request, they search directly in the database then this code doesn't make an extra request.

Comment: True. But get_posts() dataset is different from wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we can simplify it with:

```
$request  = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/posts' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$data     = rest_get_server()->response_to_data( $response, true );
```

by using [`rest_do_request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_do_request/).

Comment: Also check out the [*User Contributed Notes*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_do_request/#user-contributed-notes) in  there by Ryan McCue, e.g. the error checks, like `$response->is_error()`, before using the data.

Comment: In case, if you need to add params to WP_REST_Request, you can use
`$request->set_param('per_page', 10);`

Comment: yes and for multiple query arguments one can use `$request->set_query_params( [  'per_page' => 10, ... ] );` but `_embed` can't be activated that way.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into source code ended up with this solution. Works for me, might be useful to others as well.

```
function get_rest_items_query($post_type, $posts_per_page, $orderby = 'date', $order = 'desc') {

    $result = array();
    $args = array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order );
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    $ids = implode(',', wp_list_pluck($posts, 'ID'));

    // request
    $restRequest = new WP_REST_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/' . $post_type  );
    $restRequest->set_param('include', $ids);
    // response
    $response = rest_do_request( $restRequest );
    // _embed
    $rest = rest_get_server()->response_to_data( $response, true );

    $result['posts'] = $rest;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not efficient. By doing `get_posts()` you make a query to get all posts and by doing REST requests you make another query per post.